# How to remove a keyvalue pair in a dictionary in edit mode?

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-list

It seems that theres no problem if I wish to remove an array item in a list in edit mode. But when it comes to dictionary, I cant remove the item at all.

```
struct ExploringEditButton2: View {
    //    private var users = ["Paul", "Taylor", "Adele"]
            @State private var users = ["A": "1", "B": "2"]

            var body: some View {
                NavigationView {
                    List {
                        ForEach(Array(users.keys), id: \.self) { key in
                            Text(key)
                        }
                        .onDelete(perform: deleteOnKey)
                    }
                    .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
                }
            }

        func deleteOnKey(key: String, user: [String:String]){
                 user[key] = nil //Cannot assign through subscript: 'user' is a 'let' constant

            }

         func deleteListItem(at offsets: IndexSet) {
                print("offsets : \(offsets)")
                users.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
            }
}
```

Any idea what went wrong here?

UPDATED ANSWER:

I rewrote the deleteListItem function. Now it works.

```
         func deleteListItem(at offset: IndexSet) {
                print("offset \(offset) offset.first! : \(offset.first!)")
//                let key = Array(self.users.keys)[offset.first!]
            let key = Array(users.keys)[offset.first!]
                self.users.removeValue(forKey: key)
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working solution. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

```
struct ExploringEditButton2: View {
    //    private var users = ["Paul", "Taylor", "Adele"]
    @State private var users = ["A": "1", "B": "2"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                self.listContent(for: Array(users.keys))
            }
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
        }
    }

    private func listContent(for keys: [String]) -> some View {
        ForEach(keys, id: \.self) { key in
            Text(key)
        }
        .onDelete { indexSet in
            let key = keys[indexSet.first!]
            self.users.removeValue(forKey: key)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, thanks for the solution. Mind to explain why my solution won't work? i.e. to write a function  ( deleteOnKey ) to perform delete?

Comment: @mic, .onDelete requires specific signature closure, with IndexSet argument, the deleteOnKey does not fit it. So it is needed a way to restore key from index set  to use it with dictionary, that is done in above solution.

Comment: To address the "cannot assign ..." error that the original version generated: the `user` from which the delete was being attempted in the original `deleteOnKey(key: String, user: [String:String])` was the local read only parameter that had been passed in to the function and not the struct-level @State version.