# onDelete function for Ordered Dictionary - Cannot convert value of type 'IndexSet' to expected argument type > Int

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have an OrderedDictionary that I put into a List. How could I delete single elements from the dictionary using the onDelete function. At the moment, It is only printing the first element of the dictionary.

```
struct RecipeIngredients: View {
 
    @State var test: OrderedDictionary <String, String> = ["ab": "AC", "this will be middle": "middle", "third": "third"]
    
    
    private func listContent(for keys: [String]) -> some View {
        ForEach(keys, id: \.self) { key in
            HStack{
                    Text(key)
                        .font(.title2)
                        .foregroundColor(.green)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)      
        }
        
    }
        .onDelete { indexSet in
            let key = keys[indexSet.first!]
              self.test.removeValue(forKey: key)
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
                List{
                   listContent(for: Array(test.keys)) 
                }
                .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
                }
            }
```

Comment: This seems like it's going to be problematic, since Dictionaries, by definition, are not ordered -- you'll have undefined behavior trying to display a list of ingredients. You may want to look into OrderedDictionary: https://github.com/apple/swift-collections/blob/main/Documentation/OrderedDictionary.md

Comment: You're right, thanks. I changed my code to now reflect using the OrderedDictionary

Comment: What's the question exactly?

Comment: @RL-S attempting to delete specific elements from my Ordered Dictionary using the onDelete function.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/62369601/12299030?

Comment: Somewhat does, I edited my code with the solution I found online. What's happening is it's only printing the first key of each dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

So finally fixed this one, I figured I'll post the solution here to help anyone who may have a similiar issue.

The issue was in my drawing of the view, I didn't call test[key], which now works and deletes according to the position of the dictionary.

```
 @State var test: OrderedDictionary <String, String> = ["ab": "AC", "this will be middle": "middle", "third": "third"]
    
    
    private func listContent(for keys: [String]) -> some View {
        ForEach(keys, id: \.self) { key in
            HStack{
                Text(key)
                    .font(.title2)
                    .foregroundColor(.green)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                Text(test[key]!)
                        
                  
        }
        
    }
        .onDelete { indexSet in
            let key = test.keys[indexSet.first!]
            self.test.removeValue(forKey: key)
        }
    }


 List{
       self.listContent(for: Array(test.keys))                
      }
     .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
}
```